# how can I do a button to take a view of a fragment to another one in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm having a trouble with both the questions:

1. I can't add a functional button in a fragment, more precisely its onclick function in its fragment class .kt;
2. I need to add a view of a recyclerview to a room database (on the onclick of the button), and I'll show what's in this database in another recyclerview fragment.
   What is the best way to do the function and which logic I need to follow to do this data transfer?

Comment: "I need to add a view of a recyclerview to a room database" - What exactly do you want here? You cannot store a View inside the database.